# Bootstrap glyph icons with circle background by CSS only

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Bootstrap [glyph icons](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons) as buttons with circle background. I'd like to reach this with css only.
I found two possibilities (below), but it's do not work in IE9 compatibility mode. What is tricky in it and causes IE problems?

```
li:nth-child(even) .button-16 {
  background-color: #369;
  border: 2px solid #369;
  border-radius: 16px;
}  
li:nth-child(odd) .button-16:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #369;
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #369;
  width: 16px;
  left: -1px;
  top: -1px;
}
```

Here is working [example](http://jsbin.com/ihejom/4)

Greets!

Answer (score 0):

IE9 compatibility mode means that site is compatible with older IE wersions whitch unfortunatelly doesn't support `border-radius`.

There are some hacks to walkaround that like [Css3pie](http://css3pie.com/).

Update:
Pseudo class `:nth-child` is also not supported in IE < 9.
Here you have example site where you can check how css is supported in major browsers http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref

Comment: Thanx for pie hint, but it is not only problem. The background does not appear at all.